# Create a High Avaiebily cluster Centos in NON-Geograpical regions

Tags: linux, networking, centos, rsync, cluster

I have been looking to create an Extreme High available cluster in Centos 7.6. They have to be at least

- 2 in same data center
- 3 or more different Non- geographical locations
- Ability to expand cluster
- Sync directly, independent of location where new content is created (WordPress login)

I have been looking into MariaDB Enterprise galera cluster and rsync, together with Cloudflare Load Balancing. (rsyns has delay/time interval cron)

I also had a look at Corosync and Pacemaker together with Cloudflare Load Balancing.

But for both methods I have my doubts and there are not exactly manuals to follow that suits my needs.

Also, I need to know how to transform an existing server into a cluster without losing any data.

As far as I can see now Corosync and Pacemaker is the best option.

Can anybody give a push into the correct direction and provide a workout / workaround for this?